# Automatically setting the height of a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a textarea that I want the height to increase automatically, but it doesn't work, here is my **jQuery**:

```
$('.flat_textarea').delegate( 'textarea', 'keyup', function (){
   $(this).height( 30 );
   if(this.scrollHeight>30) 
 $(this).height(this.scrollHeight);
});

$('.flat_textarea').find( 'textarea' ).keyup();

$('.flat_textarea textarea').on("keyup",function (){
  $(this).height( 30 );
  if(this.scrollHeight>30) 
    $(this).height(this.scrollHeight);
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<form method="POST" class="flat_textarea" >
    <textarea></textarea>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of delegate() (delegate() is deprecated) - and [**keypress()**](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) instead of keyup().

**Here is a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MdVej/4/).**

Change your code to the following:

```
$('.flat_textarea').on('keypress', 'textarea', function (){
   $(this).height(30);
   if(this.scrollHeight > 30) 
     $(this).height(this.scrollHeight);
});

$('.flat_textarea').find('textarea').keypress();

$('.flat_textarea textarea').on("keypress", function (){
  $(this).height(30);
  if(this.scrollHeight > 30) 
    $(this).height(this.scrollHeight);
});
```

Comment: i didn't down voted you but i think someone did because you should put keypress before textarea in first line

Comment: @RachidO. Ok, still don't see why the downvote when it worked anyway and included a working jsFiddle, but I've changed it now, so hopefully the downvoter will do the right thing :/